# passport redirect url gives internal server error when called twice, nestjs, passport

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm using nestjs and trying to add a discord login, i use passport and guards and until now i understand that when i call the login controller

```
  @Get("discord/login")
  @UseGuards(DiscordAuthGuard)
  discord_login() {
    return "LOGIN";
  }
```

it will trigger the DiscordAuthGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class DiscordAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('discord') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const activate = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return activate;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return req.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

it will start by calling super.canActivate which will trigger the discord strategy

```
@Injectable()
export class DiscordStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'discord') {
    constructor(@Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private readonly authService: AuthenticationProvider) {
        super({
            clientID: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: "/auth/discord/redirect",
            scope: ['identify', 'email']
        });
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any) {
        const { username, email, id } = profile;
        return await this.authService.validateUser(id, username, email);
    }
}
```

it will request authentication and after i grant it in discord it will redirect me to an url like this "http://localhost:3002/auth/discord/redirect?code=8JcPaIkmq4OQuo4WJ539LtQCEdAxH8" which again wil trigger the discord guard but somehow it won't go through the same steps as before, probably and only based on what i noticed it's because i have this "?code=8JcPaIkmq4OQuo4WJ539LtQCEdAxH8" in my request, which get exchanged to an access key and everything works fine.
the problem is if i called the same url, which is already expired, i get internal server error and i get this

```
[Nest] 16412  - 12/09/2023, 7:23:54 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid "code" in request.
TokenError: Invalid "code" in request.
    at DiscordStrategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:373:12)  
    at DiscordStrategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:420:16)   
    at C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:177:45
    at C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abde1\Desktop\edu\ft_tr_backend\back_end\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1589:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

all i want is how can i handle this error and instead of returning internal server error i handle it somehow better

i tried tracking which of my functions is making that problem, but i can only see it starts when i call `const activate = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;` but nothing more
thank you in advance